# Is it possible to get elements of array that failed validation in laravel

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I have an array I want to validate, each element has an `id` field and it could also contain nested arrays, so I want to get all errors and if it's possible get elements that didn't pass validation.

I've tried to get all messages from validator `$validator->messages()->all()` but it return only messages from lowest level of arrays.

So if i pass something like this:

```
$object = [
    'field1' => 'wont_pass_validation',
    'id' => 0,
    'nested_object' => [
        'field2' => 'wont_pass_validation_either',
        'id' => 1'
     ]
]
```

it will return only `field2` message, without `field1`. 
 If there is a way to get all messages and is it possible to get failed elements so I could extract `id` fields from them?

Comment: Why do you need that data? Maybe there's a simpler way to achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @KennyHorna there is tree on frontend, data in nodes validates on backend, so I have to return id's of failed nodes and light it up

Comment: If somebody faced same problem, I solved it with making flat array from nested and validating every element. So @KennyHorna was right, there is a simplier way so achieve my goal :)